# Create new attribute as an empty model

Tags: typescript

I have a class User:

```
User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

What is difference between declaring

```
user: User = new User();
```

and

```
user = {} as User;
```

Thank you for any explaination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new User()` lets you instaniate a `User` class instance at runtime.

`{} as User` only creates an empty object. But it convinces TypeScript that it is actually a `User` instance.

---

A check with `instanceof` at runtime will let us see that only the first object is a *real* `User`.

```
const user1: User = new User();

console.log(user1 instanceof User)
// -> true


const user2: User = {} as User;

console.log(user2 instanceof User)
// -> false
```

---

We also face a potential runtime error when trying to use `user2`.

```
class User {
    id: number = 0 
}

user1.id.toExponential()
// works at compile time and at runtime

user2.id.toExponential()
// works at compile time but fails at runtime
```

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toExponential')

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgKrQKYCc4G9hx3AlgCYBccAdgK4C2ARmnALxwAMcwAviGAPanQAuccilQBGEkjqNSyAO6JhACgCUAbhCge0LuGQA6cFwDmCoWhH5efSKVDIuAM3lolwAPSu4AWgB8cPqnJkEFNRXUJdPi4AUQAPAAceZFI+PEhwZTcPGS5UAGt4SAENSji8HT88SmQ4awIagQDkyqD1TQEQgCZxYQZMNhr4CVQ1bl5tPQNjTot+a1sHJ1QXdy9fezSUYOEOsIII6PjEprSMley8gqKuErLqlKq4anIBdbLLuEb75CA)